# Deployment with Ansible from Gitlab CI, dealing with passwords

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to achieve an "password-free" deployment workflow using Gitlab CI and Ansible.
Some steps do require a password (I'm already using SSH Keys whenever I can) so I've stored those password inside an [Ansible Vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html). Next, I would just need to provide the Vault password when running the playbook.

**But how could I integrate this nicely with Gitlab CI?**

May I register a gitlab-ci job (or jobs are suitable for builds only?), which just runs the playbook providing the vault password somehow?! Can this be achieved without a password laying around in plain text?!

Also, I would be really happy if someone can point me some material that shows how we can deploy builds using Ansible. As you can notice, I've definitively found nothing about that.

Comment: is this a selfhosted gitlab-runner? if so, just use the ssh keys (or set them up) of the gitlab-runner user.

Answer (score 11):

You can set an environment variable in the GitLab CI which would hold the Ansible Vault password. In my example i called it `$ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD`

Here is the example for .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
deploy:
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo $ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD > .vault_password.txt
    - ansible-playbook -i ansible/staging.yml --vault-password-file .vault_password.txt
```

Hope this trick helps you out.

Comment: I like that answer, but would that be the same in using environment variables with the values in the CI? If there's the concern of protection, we're at the end having the password in a plain text or no?

Comment: A downside with this approach (I assume) is that Gitlab does not mask the passwords within the gitlab-vault itself? So the values that we want to keep secret would easily be exposed

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with gitlab ci, or ansible vault for that matter, but one strategy that I prefer for this kind of situation is to create a single, isolated, secure, and durable place where your password or other secrets exist. A private s3 bucket, for example. Then, give your build box or build cluster explicit access to that secure place. Of course, you'll then want to make sure your build box or cluster are also locked down, such as within a vpc that isn't publicly accessible and can only be accessed via vpn or other very secure means.

The idea is to give the machines that need your password explicit knowledge of where to get it AND seperately the permission & access they need to get it. The former does not have to be a secret (so it can exist in source control) but the latter is virtually impossible to attain without compromising the entire system, at which point you're already boned anyway.

So, more specifically, the machine that runs ansible could be inside the secure cluster. It knows how to access the password. It has permission to do so. So, it can simply get the pw, store as a variable, and use it to access secure resources as it runs. You'll want to be careful not to leak the password in the process (like piping ansible logs with the pw to somewhere outside the cluster, or even anywhere perhaps). If you want to kick off the ansible script from outside the cluster, then you would vpn in to run the ansible playbook on the remote machine.